# Should I use several activities for an app with several screens?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm building a simple application to start with. It consists of a client with three screens. In the first screen the user is prompted for an Ip to connect to a server (I use an EditText and a button). If the connection is successfully established, some data will be retrieved from the server and the client will show the data on a blank screen (I use a TextView). This would be the second screen. Then, the user could ask the server for detailed information about any data that has been retrieved from the server, which would be the third screen (I use a TextView again).

The problem is that I don't know what's the best way to go about it. I have currently one activity and one XML file containing all the components of the view (EditText, button, TextView). Until now, I've been using `setVisibility(View.GONE);`to hide certain components depending on the screen the user is in. (For example in the first screen I have to hide both TextViews).

One of the problems I'm facing is that when I put the phone in a horizontal position the components I had hidden show up again. I don't know if hiding views is the ideal thing to do for my purpose.

I've thought that maybe I should use more than one activity, shouldn't I?

I really appreciate any help you can give me to structure my first app.

Comment: The issue with your components showing up again is that you need to keep state of your Activity as the device is turned. Orientation change will cause the Activity to be destroyed and recreated, so you need to utilize onSaveInstance state to remember which views are visible and which aren't, and then set visibility again in onCreate.

Comment: @323go Why would the visibility attribute not stored automatically, when many other widget attributes are -- if an ID is assigned?

Comment: @323go Okay, you're right; visibility is not saved automatically.

Comment: @323go Thank you for your answer. So don't I need more activities? What's the purpose of having several activies then?

Comment: @user2071976, I provided a response outlining the preferred pattern for this. For this relatively small application, you can probably get away with just a single Activity, but you'll need to maintain the backstack (onBackPressed), etc, to make it fit into the Android UI paradigms. Multiple Activities would be preferred here. Keep in mind that your two TextView activities could easily share xml.

Comment: Okay, I want to use three activies then but I don't know how to pass a socket among the activities as I was commenting on the other post. I use `intent.putExtra(String name, String value)` to pass string but I don't know how to pass a socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend splitting up your App into multiple Activities/Fragments. Depending on how big the logic for each screen gets you will be glad you did it later on because each Activity only has one responsibility.

Look at your mail app for example. You got your List Activity showing you all your mails and then when you select one it starts the Detail Activity showing you the content of your mail. Each Activity is only responsible for one thing which make each one easier to write and maintain.

It also simplifies your layout definitions because each one only contains the relevant parts.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to use more than one activity but I came across the issue of "passing the socket" among the activities. The first activity should create the socket and then pass it to the other activies, I only know how to pass a String using `intent.putExtra(String name, String value)` but not a socket

Comment: You could create a static variable in your Application Object, then the second Activity can access it. You only need to make sure that the socket still is valid once the user returns to the app because the application might have been destroyed and the system will restore your second activity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is coming up a lot. Android destroys and recreates and `Activity` when the configuration changes. Screen rotation is part of the orientation. In order to avoid that, the Activity is responsible for retaining state. The mechanisms given for that are the `onCreate` and `onSaveInstanceState`. In your example, you could do something like the following:

```
int uiPhase = 1;

@Override
void onCreate( Bundle data ) {
    uiPhase = data.getInt( "uiPhase", 1 );
    // inflate layout
    setPhase( uiPhase );
}

// invoke the following each time your screen changes
void setPhase( int newPhase ) {
    uiPhase = newPhase;
    switch( uiPhase ) {
        case 1: // show UI elements for first screen, hide others
            break;
        case 2: // show UI elements for second screen, hide others
            break;
        case 3: // show UI elements for third screen, hide others
            break;
    }      
}

@Override
void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle data ) {
    data.put( "uiPhase", uiPhase );
}
```

I didn't want to complicate the pattern above too much, but a good method for setting visibility is as follows:

```
phase1view.setVisibility( uiPhase == 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
phase2view.setVisibility( uiPhase == 2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
phase3view.setVisibility( uiPhase == 3 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
```

That pulls the repetition in the `setPhase` method quite a bit together.

Answer (score -1):

Set button visibility to [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) (button will be completely "removed" -- the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or  [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (button will became "transparent" -- its space will not be available for another widgets):

use in place of

```
setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

change to

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and try
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that you got a downvote because your answer doesn't actually answer the poster's problem. He didn't have an issue with visibility until he rotated the device.